# Running PowerFlex Program on Windows

Tags: windows, computing-environment

I have an old program written in PowerFlex and I would like to see if I can get it running on Windows. Does anyone have an idea of what I need to get started doing this?

Comment: Repeated question from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742946/running-powerflex-on-windows

Comment: Yeap. I didn't know if this was a programming question or a user specific type question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the FAQ at the PowerFlex web site?

[Windows Programming](http://www.pfxcorp.com/faqwinpg.htm)

Comment: I have actually have, but before I decide to drop $2400 to convert the software, I thought I'd put a little work into getting it to work the way it is now.